# How do I edit a URL of a PHP site using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site that directs a user to a php page, after filling out a form, to /form.php?id=whateverID?password=whateverPassword (this is an example).
I would like to use .htaccess to show the URL as being form.php.

At the of the day I am looking to count how many users were directed to the form.php pages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont think you need .htaccess for that, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a GET method, use a POST

```
<form action='form.php' method='POST'>
...
```

and to access it in your php use the `$_POST` variable